# How can I fix WebStorm warning "Unresolved function or method" for "require" (Firefox Add-on SDK)

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, webstorm, firefox-addon-sdk

I'm using [WebStorm](https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/) 7 for [Firefox Add-on SDK](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK) development.

WebStorm shows a warning: "Unresolved function or method" for `require()`.

I want to get rid of the warning.

```
var pageMod = require("sdk/page-mod");
```

NOTE:I already configured JavaScript-library (refer /lib/sdk globals).

**Environment:**

- WebStorm 7.0.2
- Windows 7 64bit
- Firefox Add-on SDK 1.15beta1

Comment: var pageMod = new require("sdk/page-mod"); may solve the issue. Notice the 'new' in the code

Comment: I had the same problem with WebStorm 8

Comment: Yep. Same here. This is really annoying.

Answer (score 385):

Do you mean that `require()` is not resolved? You need to either add `require.js` to your project or enable `Node.js Globals` predefined library in Settings/Languages and Frameworks/JavaScript/Libraries.

(Edited settings path by @yurik)

In WebStorm 2016.x-2017.x: make sure that the Node.js Core library is enabled in `Settings (Preferences) | Languages & Frameworks | Node.js and NPM`

In IntelliJ 2018.3.2+ go to `Settings (Preferences) | Languages & Frameworks | Node.js and NPM` and enable `Coding assistance for Node.js`

Comment: Thank you lena. and sorry my english poor.(>_<;)

I want to cleanup warning on webstorm-editor.
(script execution is no problem. )

Firefox-Addon-SDK conforms commonjs, but not uses node.js. 
"require" method defined <sdkroot>/app-extension/bootstrap.js
I set bootstrap.js to External Libraries, but not clear "unresolved" warning.

<code>
    let require = cuddlefish.Require(loader, module);

function loadSandbox(uri) {
  let sandbox = ...
  sandbox.require = function (id) {
    return Object.freeze({ ... });
  };
  return sandbox;
</code>

Comment: Useful answer! BTW, in my webstorm 9, The location is:   
*Language & Frameworks -> Javascript -> Libraries*     ;
Another approach is to search for "Libraries"

Comment: In Webstorm 9, you can also right-click on "require", and choose "Use Javascript Library->Node.js Globals"

Comment: Enable the NodeJS plugin if 'Node.js Globals' is missing from the library list.

Comment: I tried everything in this tread and nothing worked, but when I updated to the latest webstorm, hey presto, no more errors!  Give it a go, I'm using Webstorm 2017.3 (the problem was happening in Webstorm 11) and I no longer get the problem

Comment: Sometimes you have to turn that option off, save the settings, then turn it on again for the error to go away.

Comment: FYI: I had to turn my node assist OFF, invalid caches and restart WebStorm and then turn it back ON to get it working. WebStorm 2018.3.5

Comment: I had to do what @Reactgular said above. WebStorm 2021.2

Answer (score 236):

Webstorm 11 and 2016.2.3

Enable `Node.js Core library` in Webstorm settings.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I just wanted to add on that I had the same problem and although my core library was already enabled, going to the settings screen seemed to fix the problem.

Comment: didn't work for me using typescript with the latest version of node and webstorm.  Still on the hunt for a fix for us angular2 people.  Usage inside a component definition `styles: [require('./app.component.css')]`

Comment: I still have the error in the compiler  error TS2304: Cannot find name 'require'.

Comment: @SuperUberDuper You should replace 'require' with `import {*} from 'node module'` and specify `"target": "CommonJS"` inside **tsconfig.json**

Comment: Worked as soon as I enabled it in Webstorm preferences (not the project settings)

Comment: weird, not working in webstorm 2022.1.1

Answer (score 62):

After spending an hour trying to get this to work using all solutions found online, this finally did the trick!

File -> Invalidate Caches/Restart...

Comment: This worked for me with WebStrom 2017.2.4 to resolve an issue where Array.push was falsely indicated as a method that didn't exist.

Comment: Worked for me after update ***PhpStorm 2017.2.4*** Build number ***PS-172.4155.41***. Problem was, the IDE ignored ES6 specs.

Comment: Worked for me in WebStorm 2021.2.3

Comment: Can`t stress enough how CORRECT this answer is.

Comment: Same for IntelliJ IDEA 2023.2.5

Answer (score 47):

In PHPStorm, it's a bit easier: you can just search for NPM in settings or:

```
File > Settings > Language & Frameworks > Node.js and NPM
```

Then click the enable button (apparently in new versions, it is called "Coding assistance for Node").

Answer (score 18):

Working with Intellj 2016, Angular2, and Typescript... the only thing that worked for me was to get the Typescript Definitions for NodeJS

[Get node.d.ts from DefinitelyTyped on GitHub](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/node/node.d.ts)

Or just run:

`npm install @types/node --save-dev`

Then in tsconfig.json, include

```
"types": [
     "node"
  ]
```

Comment: Thank You! I feel like I've been searching for ages! Just installing @types/node calmed down WebStorm; I'll see about the compiler later.

Comment: Thank you, this worked for me. For me, it used to work using the accepted answer here, but it somehow started conflicting as I added new libraries. This fixed my problem again

Answer (score 16):

In WebStorm 2018.3 a bit different interface
[image]

Comment: This working! But in March 2023 using node 21.6.2 WebStorm 2023.3.5 not working, I downgrade node to 20.9.0 and works fine! 
The Webstorm seems not all support newest versions of Node.

Answer (score 7):

**On WebStorm 2016.3**

1. Press <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd> (open terminal)
2. Run this command:

   ```
   npm install require.js
   ```

Answer (score 5):

For WebStorm 2019.3 File > Preferences or Settings > Languages & Frameworks > Node.js and NPM -> Enable Coding assitance for NodeJs

Note that the additional packages that you want to use are included.

Comment: It's so easy it might just work. 

Answer (score 4):

Disable JetBrains Inspections and get the ESLint plugin.

The only thing that `File | Invalidate caches and restart` does for me is reset it long enough to trick me into thinking the error is gone. Once the inspections run again the error comes back like a gift that keeps on giving.

I saved myself all that frustration by disabling all JetBrains inspections  (`Editor` > `Inspections` > uncheck `JavaScript`) Then I installed the ESLint plugin.

The inspection that causes "Unresolved function method" can be turned off by going to JetBrains inspections  (`Editor` > `Inspections` > `JavaScript`) and searching for "Unresolved Javascript" and turning off "Unresolved Javascript function" and "Unresolved Javascript variable"

I killed them all and have edited my code hassle free ever since.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, Here I have seen a lot of answers already given,
I want to add some more that are fixed unresolved function/method/variable warning.

That is resolved "unresolved function or method for 'require' and some other warning"

```
Go -> Preferences-> Languages & Frameworks -> Node.js and NPM, then checkmark the "Coding assistance for Node.js"
```

If you still see this type of warning, unresolved variable or something like that, you can manually disable these warnings by followings.

```
Go -> Preferences-> Editor-> Inspections-> JavaScript-> General.
```

and you will find a list and just unchecked what warning you want to disable and then apply.

Answer (score 2):

Another solution that helped me a lot is to update all libs in "Node.js and NPM". You need just mark all libs and click blue arrow - 'update' [image]

Answer (score 0):

None of the above solutions worked for me. Something crazy happened. There was a `tsconfig.json` sitting in one of my directories. Once I deleted that it started working.

Answer (score -2):

File->Settings->Languages & Frameworks->JavaScript

[image: Instruction]