# Webstorm doesn`t recognize my global functions when I use "require"

Tags: javascript, node.js, require, webstorm

Every time I use:

```
var bla = require('./directory/bla.js')
```

All global functions starts to be "unresolved function or method".

Any ideas?

Comment: So your IDE is giving you errors, but does the code work ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20136714/how-can-i-fix-webstorm-warning-unresolved-function-for-require-firefox-a

Comment: Do you have an example of how you declare your functions?

Comment: how do you define your globals? WebStorm indeed doesn't resolve functions defined in other files in Node.js projects unless they are available through require/added to Node.js global namespace

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to add `require` as a global at the top of your JavaScript file.

```
/*global
    setBorderlessEvents
*/
```