# Why does node.js plugin in Intellij-Idea don`t work?

Tags: node.js, intellij-idea, plugins

I installed plugin for Intellij-Idea and it doesn`t work. Why can it be? As you can see the require word doesn`t become yellow.[image]

And here is my plugin installed:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please make sure to enable `Node.js Core` library in `File | Settings | Languages & Frameworks | Node.js and NPM`

Answer (score 0):

- I like to hover over things that are underlined to give me clues as to where to start. Your `"path"` and `"require"` are underlined. Your errors might say `Unused local variable 'path'` and `Unresolved method or function require()`
- You might not have installed node in the current project. If you don't have node installed, try:

  1. `npm init` to create a package.json file. 
     IntelliJ will walk you through creating the file. You can just press enter all the way through if you want and edit it later.
  2. `npm install express --save` (replace express with whatever library you are trying to use) to save library in the dependencies list

[Installing express](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/installing.html)

[How can I fix WebStorm warning “Unresolved function or method” for “require”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20136714/how-can-i-fix-webstorm-warning-unresolved-function-or-method-for-require-fi)