# How to enable Jasmine support in node.js intellisense

Tags: javascript, node.js, jasmine, webstorm

I've installed jasmine in my project. Now when I write the following in `*.spec.js`:

```
describe(...)
```

I get the warning:

> Unresolved function or method `describe`

I've read in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20148144/2545680) that I can add `jasmine` as a library and thought that this should fix it.

[image]

But it doesn't seem to work - the warning is still there. What am I missing?

Comment: if `jasmine` is downloaded in your `node-modules`, IntelliJ should pick that up and not show `Unresolved function...`. I just checked by Ctrl+clicking on a describe, led me to `jasmine-1.3.1.js` inside `node-modules/jasmine-nod/...`

Comment: @tanmay, yeah, that what I expected, but it doesn't pick it up :(. I noticed you use `jasmine-node` instead of [jasmine-npm](https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine-npm). Is it a better choice?

Comment: It's not maintained anymore (last commit in 2014).. you're better off with `jasmine-npm`.. also try checking `<project>/node_modules` fully if you haven't already.. if that helps

Comment: @tanmay, got it, thanks, I've figured out the problem. Check [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43910794/2545680)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with [the way globals are defined](https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine/blob/master/lib/jasmine-core/node_boot.js#L33) in `Jasmine`:

```
  // returns object with `describe`, `it`... properties
  var jasmineInterface = jasmineRequire.interface(jasmine, env);

  extend(global, jasmineInterface);
```

If globals are defined in this way WebStorm can't pick them up. It seems to be capable to handle only simply case like top-level functions:

```
function describe() {}
```

It's still possible to have intelli-sense support by downloading and installing DefinitelyTyped package:

[image]

Comment: globals defined this way can't be resolved during static code analysis. In such cases, installing typescript stubs is the right way to go

Comment: @lena, yeah, that's what I thought. Thanks for the confirmation