# unresolved function or method JavaScript yii2

Tags: javascript, jquery, printing

I want to print the contents of `HTML`. For this I have created a function and in this function I have passed the `div` ID in it. But the choose shown the following message.

[image]

My `javascript` is under `document.ready` function

```
function printDiv(divName) {
  var printContents = document.getElementById(divName).innerHTML;
  var originalContents = document.body.innerHTML;
  document.body.innerHTML = printContents;
  window.print();
  document.body.innerHTML = originalContents;
}
```

And here I am getting error `Unused function printDev`

I have tried to enable [NodeJS and NPM](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40365578/6854117) but still no use

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: document.ready(function(){function printDiv???...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My javascript is under document.ready function

If you defined the printDiv function inside another function, it's not visible to your onclick HTML parameter.

You can either define it as a global function, or add an eventListener to your element inside your document.ready function :

```js
function printDiv(divName) {
       var printContents = document.getElementById(divName).innerHTML;
       var originalContents = document.body.innerHTML;
       document.body.innerHTML = printContents;
       window.print();
       document.body.innerHTML = originalContents;
}

$( document ).ready(function() {
    document.getElementById("printButton").addEventListener("click", function() {
        printDiv('print');
    });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <input type="button" id="printButton" value="Print PDF"></input>
  <div id="print"></div>
</body>
</html>
```